# How to import CSV file into postgres using COPY - Skip few columns?

Tags: postgresql, csv

I have a table in Postgres with only 2 columns

```
CREATE table dummy(col1 char(10), col2 char(10));
```

The CSV file has the following columns:

```
gid        prov             name        pop1996
4468       BC              VANCOUVER    514008
4501       BC               SURREY      304477
4473       BC               BURNABY     179209
4485       BC               RICHMOND    148867
```

How can I copy gid and name only from this file using `\COPY`?

Comment: Probably duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618232/copy-a-few-of-the-columns-of-a-csv-file-into-a-table

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind creating other tables you can follow the Q/A @Jan Marek pointed out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12619903/318174

If you can't create additional tables than you can do this:

You will need to preprocess the CSV file first by eliminating the columns you don't want. The easiest way is using UNIX cut.

```
cat file.csv | cut -d '\t' 1,3 > processed.csv
```

If your CSV file has some escaping needed you can use a [python script I wrote](https://gist.github.com/agentgt/1383185) a long time ago that is exactly like cut but respects CSV.

```
cat file.csv | csvcut.py -d '\t' 1,3 > processed.csv
```

Next you load up psql and enter:

```
\copy your_table (col1,col2) FROM '/path/to/processed.csv' DELIMITER '\t' CSV;
```

Comment: Python installs on windows so you can use my python script.

Comment: Oh you will still need to pipe the csv file to the python script. Well I recommend if you haven't already install Powershell, Cygwin, Babun or Gow. Once you do that open the better shell and run the command.

Comment: Is there a way out, If i don't want to install anything new ?

Comment: Don't actually have to pre-process the file. Can directly copy `FROM PROGRAM 'cat /path/to/file.csv | cut -d '\t' 1,3'` instead.