# Copy few of the columns of a csv file into a table error

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv, copy, etl

[image: Excel sheet data to import into postgres table with only few columns]

I have data in excel sheet named with district.csv needs to import only few columns from excel to postgres table named with hc_court_master

```
copy hc_court_master (district_cd, category,category1,shrt_nm,court_name)
from 'D:\district.csv'
with (format csv)
```

I was getting the error

```
ERROR: extra data after last expected column
SQL state: 22P04
Context: COPY hc_court_master, line 1: "court_code,court_name,short_c_name,category,dist_no,dist_name,category1"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is two problem:

1. You can not copy just few column from csv. And you can not change their order.
2. Just use `HEADER` keyword in with clause to ignore header in csv file.

> ```
>  copy hc_court_master (court_code, court_name, short_c_name,
>        category, dist_no, dist_name, category1)
>  from 'D:\district.csv'
>  with (format csv, HEADER)
> ```

If you do not want all fields in your table you can:

1. ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN after importing
2. Import into temp table and after that run INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here you can not to load selected fields from CSV, only whole data. So

```
begin; -- Start transaction

do $$
begin
  create temp table t( -- Create table to load data from CSV
    court_code text, -- There are whole list of columns ...
    court_name text,
    short_c_name text,
    category text,
    dist_no text,
    dist_name text,
    category1 text)  on commit drop;
  copy t from '/home/temp/a.csv' with (
    format CSV,
    header -- To ignore first line
    );
end $$;

insert into hc_court_master (district_cd, category,category1,shrt_nm,court_name)
select <appropriate columns> from t;
commit;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
copy hc_court_master (district_cd, category,category1,shrt_nm,court_name)
from 'D:\district.csv'
with (format csv)
```

i think sql above will work only if your csv contains only required columns (district_cd, category,category1,shrt_nm,court_name).

You can delete extra columns then try to upload.

Please refer below link

[Copy a few of the columns of a csv file into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618232/copy-a-few-of-the-columns-of-a-csv-file-into-a-table)