# Error during copy command in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, copy

I'm trying to insert data into my table in Postgres with the `COPY` command and I had the following error:

`ERROR:  extra data after last expected column`

There is my COPY command :

`copy basic_data_cs from '/data/tmp/basic_data.csv' delimiter ';' header csv;`

There is my table structure :

`CREATE FOREIGN TABLE  basic_data_cs 
(  oid4 BIGINT  ,  oid3 BIGINT ,  date_creation date ,  date_modif date ,  id_princ text ,  nb_ref INTEGER ,  coobox INTEGER ,  otype_bin INTEGER ,  ra REAL ,  ra_prec SMALLINT ,  dec REAL ,  dec_prec SMALLINT ,  coo_err_maja FLOAT ,  coo_err_maja_prec SMALLINT , coo_err_mina FLOAT ,  coo_err_mina_prec SMALLINT ,  coo_err_angle SMALLINT ,  coo_qual TEXT ,  coo_wavelength TEXT ,  coo_bibcode TEXT ,  pmra REAL , pmra_prec SMALLINT ,  pmdec REAL ,  pmdec_prec SMALLINT , pm_err_maja FLOAT ,  pm_err_maja_prec SMALLINT ,  pm_err_mina FLOAT ,  pm_err_mina_prec SMALLINT ,  pm_err_angle SMALLINT ,  pm_qual text ,  pm_bibcode text ,  plx_value REAL ,  plx_prec SMALLINT ,  plx_error FLOAT ,  plx_error_prec SMALLINT ,  plx_qual TEXT , plx_bibcode TEXT ,  rvz_type TEXT ,  rvz_radvel REAL ,  rvz_radvel_prec SMALLINT , rvz_redshift REAL ,  rvz_redshift_prec SMALLINT ,  rvz_error FLOAT ,   rvz_error_prec SMALLINT ,  rvz_qual TEXT ,  rvz_nature TEXT ,  rvz_wavelength TEXT ,  rvz_bibcode TEXT ,  sp_type TEXT ,  sp_type_bin BIGINT ,  sp_qual text ,  sp_nature text , sp_bibcode text ,  morph_type text ,  morph_type_bin INTEGER ,  morph_qual text ,  morph_bibcode text ,  galdim_majaxis FLOAT ,  galdim_majaxis_prec SMALLINT ,  galdim_minaxis FLOAT , galdim_minaxis_prec SMALLINT ,  galdim_angle SMALLINT ,  galdim_incl SMALLINT ,  galdim_qual text ,  galdim_wavelength text ,  galdim_bibcode text ,  nb_parents INTEGER ,  nb_children INTEGER ,  nb_siblings INTEGER ,  id_princ_select text ,  hpx BIGINT ,  otype text ,  vlsr REAL ,  vlsr_prec SMALLINT ,  vlsr_error REAL ,  vlsr_error_prec SMALLINT ,  vlsr_wavelength text ,  vlsr_bibcode text) server cstore_server;`

And there is a line from my csv file : 
`10396425;;2016-08-02;2016-08-02;SDSS J001954.03+025717.0;1;11278;-14680064;4.975139;7;2.954735;7;;-1;;-1;32767;C;O;2014A&A...563A..54P;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;z;263064.159868091;0;2.9147;4;0.0003;4;C;s;O;2014A&A...563A..54P;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;(0.0868325562943782 , 0.0515698542739147);4635816;QSO;;;;;;;;;;`

This command worked for an another 'classic' table with the same CSV file and the same command.

Answer (score 0):

This would be because , your table contains 78 columns and your csv delimited file has 82 entries.[image]

[image]

Comment: This csv file worked for another table with the same structure and it works great. Myabe it is because this table is a foreign table ?

Answer (score 0):

Either you get a new csv with same columns as table or you can try 
[check the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618232/copy-a-few-of-the-columns-of-a-csv-file-into-a-table) from there