# Need to substitute commas in TEXT (BASH)

Tags: sql, bash, postgresql

Trying this again...

I have a survey that I'm trying to analyze in SQL and some people have commented using a comma (i.e. "Sick today, need Vit C.") and when I'm trying to load it into SQL that comma is reading as the delimiter and not reading the last column.

My csv is delimited by commas so I understand whats happening I just don't know how to change only commas inside text.

Should I download the file from google sheets as tab separated?

Can I sub the any commas in that column (the comments section) to be a space using sed, grep, tr or awk?

I setup `questionnaire` table in postgresSQL and I set `comments` column to `TEXT`.

I have the `VassarXCTFReadinessQuestionnaire.csv` saved in my server.

I'm converting `VassarXCTFReadinessQuestionnaire.csv` to `quest_ready.csv` with:

```
cat VassarXCTFReadinessQuestionnaire.csv | cut -d',' -f1-11 | grep -v ',NA' > quest_ready.csv
```

Actual data in `VassarXCTFReadinessQuestionnaire.csv`:

W/ Comments and comma in comment column:

```
11/7/18,Jackson Picker,3,3,3,3,4,3,7,"feeling alright, same situation with the hip.",4.1,,
```

w/o comments:

```
11/7/18,Hannah Happy,4,2,2,3,3,4,9,,4.35,,
```

w/ comments w/o comma:

```
11/6/18,Hannah Happy,4,2,2,3,3,4,9,All Good!,4.35,,
```

Desired result in quest_ready.csv is:

```
11/7/18,Jackson Picker,3,3,3,3,4,3,7,"feeling alright same situation with the hip.",4.1,,
11/7/18,Hannah Happy,4,2,2,3,3,4,9,,4.35,,
11/6/18,Hannah Happy,4,2,2,3,3,4,9,All Good!,4.35,,
```

THANKS!

Comment: How are you loading the CSV into SQL? If you use `LOAD DATA INFILE`, the `FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` clause should make it work.

Comment: Also, what RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.?

Comment: New to all of this so I appreciate every bit of help! I'm loading it from local to remote server via scp -r then processing the file1 into a new file2 then login into postgresSQL on my server and loading it an already created table with COPY table_name FROM '/home/server/file_name.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;

Answer (score 0):

Crude implementation, but:

```
#!/bin/bash

string=$(grep -o '".*"' my.csv | tr ',' ' ')

before=$(cat my.csv | cut -d',' -f1-9 | grep -v ',NA')
after=$(cat my.csv | cut -d',' -f12 | grep -v ',NA')
echo "${before},${string},${after}"
```

Output:

`11/7/18,Jackson Pierce,3,3,3,3,4,3,7,"feeling alright  same situation with the hip.",3.56`

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this at the terminal level. This does work but it just returns the value and doesn't change in the .csv Very new to this so I'm lost. Thanks, and sorry!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `cut` to select fields when the delimiter can appear inside a field; it doesn't provide any way to escape delimiters.

Instead, you should copy directly from the `VassarXCTFReadinessQuestionnaire.csv` into the database table, rather than trying to convert it first.

Use the `QUOTE` parameter to the `COPY` command so that it recognizes quoted fields and doesn't use the commas inside as delimiters.

```
COPY table_name 
FROM '/home/server/file_name.csv' 
DELIMITER ',' 
QUOTE '"'
```

If this file has extra fields that don't correspond to table columns, see

[Copy a few of the columns of a csv file into a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618232/copy-a-few-of-the-columns-of-a-csv-file-into-a-table)

Comment: Getting this 'ERROR:  extra data after last expected column' because it's still recognizing the quote in the comments as a column separator.

Comment: If you have quotes inside the columns you need to escape them, and then use the `ESCAPE` option. See all the options at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-copy.html

Comment: Can you edit the question and add examples of the CSV lines?

Comment: Updated my question